# Can I add custom admin page in Ektron

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

Consider this example and tell is that possible?

i have a custom api to show my survey analytics (eg: api return a table of values )
My ektron site owner should show this analytics in their settings section in work area and the ektron admin group should  only show this page.Adding custom page to setting section is possible or not?

Comment: We can add page by editing the workareanavigationtrees.aspx.cs file in Workarea. I think adding page to settings is not a better option in Ektron ,Smart Desktop widget is the best option.

Comment: That is definitely the best option and is there for that purpose. There also will be more options for that sort of extensibility soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this (as mentioned in the comments to your question) is to encapsulate the functionality in a custom widget for use on the [Smart Desktop](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v8.60/Reference/Mobile/Advanced/Content/Getting_Started/Workarea_Smart_Desktop.htm).

It's a little confusing (at least on v8.7 sp2) to know how to get your custom widget to appear as an option in the Smart Desktop, so here's a quick run-down.  *(There was an old forum post on the old [Ektron developer site](http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=29362), but it appears the name of the default widget space has changed since then, plus I've added some more details here.)*

1. Create your widget(s) and save them in the /Workarea/Widgets/ folder.
2. In the workarea, go to `Settings > Configuration > Personalizations > Widgets` and click on the "Synchronize widgets from /widgets/ folder" button.  The button text makes it sound like this is only for PageBuilder widgets, but this also will synchronize the list of widgets found in the /Workarea/Widgets/ folder.
3. Go to `Settings > Configuration > Personalizations > Widget Space`. You should see a widget space called "UserSmartDesktop".  Click the edit button next to that.
4. select the widgets that you want to be available for users on their smart desktop.

At this point, you should be able to go to the Desktop tab in the workarea and add your widget to either your own smart desktop or the default one.  I'm not sure if there's a way to make widgets available to only certain groups of users, but you can definitely build that permissions check into the widget itself, so that if your account isn't part of the admin group (or whatever group(s) you choose) then it doesn't load any real data and instead shows an "Access Denied" type of message.